# Table row exapnd collapse jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a expand/collapse nested table structure like below.
Here when i click a parent all other previously expanded parents at that level and its child must be collapsed.

[image]

Initially Application(1) is expanded, have 2 child's(Image 1).
When i click Application(2) the childs of Application(1) must be collapsed (Image 2).
This should be applicable at all levels. Something like find siblings and hide, but except the clicked one. How can i do this

```
siblings().find().not(clicked).hide();
```

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vivekcek/rFKJc/

Parent rows have a class 'parent' and id='[id]'. Child rows have a class by appending parent id class=child-[id].

```
 $('tr.parent')
.css("cursor", "pointer")
.attr("title", "Click to expand/collapse")
.click(function () {
$(this).siblings('.child-' + this.id).toggle();
});
$('tr[class*=child-]').hide().children('td');
```

Comment: '$(this).siblings('.child-').not($(this)).hide();' i tried this but not working

Comment: Also when clicking parents child are not collapsed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var $trs = $('tr.parent')
.css("cursor", "pointer")
.attr("title", "Click to expand/collapse")
.click(function () {
    var $sibs = $(this).siblings('.child-' + this.id).toggle();
    $(this).siblings().not($sibs).not('.parent').hide()
});
$('tr[class*=child-]').hide().children('td');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZBpVW/)

Comment: But i expand up to leaf. Then clicked its first parent(vivek) that parent will be collapsed. Once again when i click this parent (Vivek). i see that previously expanded items are not colapsed up to leaf

Comment: Parent1 -> Child1 -> {Parent1.1 ->Child1.1{Parent1.1.1 -Child1.1.1}} i will expand up to child 1.1.1 Then when i click to Parent1 all other level must be at the initial state

Comment: Under the click i think i may need to use '$this.closest().next().toggle' something like that

Answer (score 0):

This solved all problems

```
         var $trs = $('tr.parent')
        .css("cursor", "pointer")
        .attr("title", "Click to expand/collapse")
        .click(function () {
                var $sibs = $(this).siblings('.child-' + this.id).toggle();
                $(this).siblings().not($sibs).not('.parent').hide();
                $($sibs).find('tr[class*=child-]').hide();
        });

    $('tr[class*=child-]').hide().children('td');
```